# OpenTelemetry for .NET 6 applications on Google Cloud Run

Tags: asp.net, .net, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, open-telemetry

If I have an ASP.NET application running on .NET 6 instrumented with the standard OpenTelemetry libraries, is there any low-touch destination for my application to send all trace and logging information?

Perhaps something like a well known host and IP thats exposed inside my environment?

Comment: If you want to use Cloud Operations to log/trace your instrumented code, you must export the OT data to Cloud Operations. In some languages (Java, Go, Node, Python) libraries exist to export the data. In your case, I found nothing. You have to write your exporter yourselves.

Comment: Is there any information somewhere that I can review to do this?

Comment: I'm too weak in OT to help you. Maybe by reverse engineering in the already existing library?